# Suppress warning ~ Actual value of parameter X is always Y

Tags: java, android

My Android Java code has a class that includes `cancel` method:

```
private void hide(int aniDuration) {
    if (!isVisible) return;
    if (runnable != null) handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
    isVisible = false;
    if (aniDuration > 0) {
        fadeInOut(false, aniDuration);
    }
    else {
        notifierLayout.setAlpha(0.0f);
        notifierLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}

private void hide() { hide(animateDuration); }

@SuppressWarnings({"unused", "WeakerAccess"})
public void cancel() { hide(); }

@SuppressWarnings({"unused", "WeakerAccess"})
public void cancel(int aniDuration) {
    hide(aniDuration);
}
```

But since (so far) I call this `cancel` method just once with the parameter `aniDuration = 0`, the Android Studio debugger shows the following warning message:

> Actual value of parameter "aniDuration" is always "0"

[image]

Besides of using `@SuppressWarnings("all")`, how could I suppress this type of warning?

Answer (score 98, accepted):

You can suppress it with

**JAVA:**

```
@SuppressWarnings("SameParameterValue")
```

**KOTLIN:**

```
@Suppress("SameParameterValue")
```

Comment: For future reference: When Android Studio gives you a warning, it also gives you an option to suppress it. Alt-enter on the warning and select one of the suppress options in the quick fix menu.

Comment: laalto: Actually, recent versions of Android Studio no longer give you the option to suppress it easily. It used to act the way you describe in older versions.

Comment: Is there a list of the `@SuppressWarnings` for Java &  `@Suppress` for Kotlin?

Comment: It doesn't work with warning like "Result of X is always Y". Do you know some fix that doesn't involve suppressing that warning altogether?

Answer (score 7):

File > Settings > Editor > Inspections > Find:"Actual method parameter is the same constant"
uncheck and android studio restart

Comment: I like this better than @SuppresWarning, as don't want my code to have noises :)